# Adding cell to row using Smartsheet API in Python

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to add a new row to a sheet in in Smartsheet.
I iterate through the sheet to find the ColumnId with header "Document Type", create a new cell object and set the .columnId property to this found ID. For some reason, I receive an error "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.columnId."

Please see output below! My cell.columnId is of type int and matches the columnId of the "Document Type" header.

Thanks.

```
import smartsheet

smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token)
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheetID)

for column in sheet.columns:
    if column.title == "Document Type":
        thisColumn = column.id

newRow = smartsheet_client.models.Row()
newCell = smartsheet_client.models.Cell()
newCell.columnID = thisColumn
newCell.displayValue = 'Test'
print("newCell.columnID ==", newCell.columnID)
print("type(newCell.columnID) ==", type(newCell.columnID))
print()
newRow.cells.append(newCell)
smartsheet_client.Sheets.add_rows(sheetID, newRow)
```

When I run this code, I get the following output + error.

```
newCell.columnID == 7729112579106692
type(newCell.columnID) == <class 'int'>

{"response": {"statusCode": 400, "reason": "Bad Request", "content": {"detail": {"index": 0}, "errorCode": 1012, "message": "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.columnId.", "refId": "vrktl1049bea"}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the following code will achieve the goal you've described. It creates a new row in the specified sheet, and populates a single cell in that new row (i.e., the cell within the **Document Type** column) with the value `Test`.

```
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheetID)

for column in sheet.columns:
    if column.title == "Document Type":
        thisColumn = column.id

# Define cell object (for the value in the 'Document Type' column) 
newCell = smartsheet_client.models.Cell({
    'column_id': thisColumn,
    'object_value': 'Test'
})

# Create row that contains the cell value defined previously
row = smartsheet_client.models.Row({
    'cells': [newCell]
})

# Add row to sheet
result = smartsheet_client.Sheets.add_rows(sheetID, [row])
```

Comment: Thank you! Still unsure why mine didn't work but regardless, your answer works and is enough to get me going and finish the script I'm writing.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
newCell.columnID = thisColumn
```

Should be:

```
newCell.column_id = thisColumn
```

Additionally, instead of

```
newCell.displayValue = 'Test'
```

you may want to use

```
newCell.value = 'Test'
```

You can find the specific documentation for this [here](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#update-rows)

Comment: Thanks. This is something I don't understand. Why is it referenced as columnID in some places in the documentation, but in the python code example it's "column_id". I had the same problem with setting the row.parent_id (and thought it was parentId based on the documentation)

Comment: I *think* this is due to the smartsheet-python-sdk package creators wanting to conform to python naming conventions. Unfortunately, it is not clear in the documentation what the alternates are for python. I've had to dig into the package's github repo on many occasions to find how it is supposed to work.